# cURL with SPLObject - "curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource"

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL function in PHP which opening a file handler, creates a file as mode 'w' and save the data (txt) inside it which it is getting through cURL.

My Code is:

```
    $ch          =  curl_init('http://www.myserver.com/api/data');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);               
                    $filehandle = new SplFileObject('myfile.txt', 'w');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $filehandle);
                    curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
```

If I use  `$filehandle = @fopen(myfile.txt', 'w');` It works fine. But with `SplFileObject` it is throwing this error:

> curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource

Comment: missing quote, typo? `$filehandle = new SplFileObject('myfile.txt', 'w');`

Comment: it is missed in typing. check the error msg. its related to file handle resource

Comment: I see, what you're trying to do isn't possible, as `SplFileObject` does not create a stream resource, rather, you can't access it like this.

Comment: @Kisaragi what is stream resource? and what should I do in cURL? what else can be more appropriate better than fopen?

Comment: What's wrong with `fopen()`? `SplFileObject` creates an OOP interface for a particular file, so in order to write, you'd need to call `$obj->write('...');`. I don't think this is possible with curl. You can use `file_put_contents()`, `fwrite()`... there are many options

Comment: my data is received with curl. so i cannot write with file_put_contents() of fwrite. Data is with cURL

Comment: You can use `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to declare a callback, where you can then use `file_put_contents()` or whatever you'd like

Comment: please can you write as code so I can understand